# How Get is better than Post in Basic Authentication apache http client (Java Programming)

Tags: java, authentication, post, get, httpclient

I have heard that Post is most preferred while reaching a link which has password /sensitive information.

Q1.I know that Post is better than Put for Name-value pair parameters as ,the Get exposes it in URL and Post doesn't. But if we are talking about authentication ,How does it matter what method i use as  i set the Credentials to the HttpClient not to the HttpGet or HttpPost.So  credentials are not getting exposed anyway .The encapsulation of Name-value pairs is benefited by using POST.

```
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();

credsProvider.setCredentials(
    new AuthScope(target.getHostName(), target.getPort()),
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "passwd"));
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
    .build();
```

Q2. Again i can set the credentials as header to httppost as well to httpget like this..

```
String encoding = new BASE64Encoder().encode("user:passwd".getBytes());
httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
```

Where does the post method takes precedence over get method?

Answer (score 0):

I think whoever said post is better than get when using passwords meant that the passwords would be part of the url in the get request, which would obviously be bad.